# Tensor product of two linear map and its matrix representation

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Suppose $T_1: \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be any linear map and wrt a basis $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ the matrix of $T_1$ is $M$, aand $T_2:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^m$ be another linear map whose matrix wrt $\{f_1,\dots,f_n\}$ is $N$

Now $T_1\otimes T_2:\mathbb{R}^{mn}\to\mathbb{R}^{mn}$ is a linear map and say wrt to basis $\{e_i\otimes f_j\}_{i=1,j=1}^{m,n}$ the matrix of this map $K$

Is there any computation or formula or theorem which says any relation between $K,M,N$? or can we get $K$ from $M,N$?

Comment: $K$ is exactly the Kronecker Product of $M$ and $N$.

Comment: where I can get a nice proof?

Comment: see problem 20 on page 408 of Roman's Advanced Linear Algebra, 3rd ed.